# Opposite way of saying “got me wrong”

Tags: phrase-usage, phrases

Is it correct to say the first one in the opposite way of the second one?

> 1. You got me right.

> 2. Don't get me wrong.

Comment: It's non-standard English, but no doubt you could hear it in a pub somewhere.

Comment: The explicitly negated form ***Don't get me wrong*** is a well-established *colloquial* usage, but it doesn't reflect a "productive" idiomatic form. That's to say, native speakers wouldn't normally extrapolate from that even to non-negated *I did explain it to him, but **he got me wrong***. And they'd be even less likely to make the further extrapolation to *John didn't understand my explanation, but **Jane got me right***. But I suggest that for *learners* it would be best to stick to "mainstream" English - ***You [don't] understand me***.

Comment: @FumbleFingers, So as I understood it's possible to say so but it's informal, right?

Comment: "You got me right" is not standard English. It *would* be informal if someone said it, but no-one does.

Comment: But the **opposite** of "Don't get me wrong" would be either "Don't get me right" or "Get me wrong", neither of which we say, because they are absurd! And the first sentence is in the past tense but the second is an imperative. What are you trying to say? If you want to say (past tense), "Yes! You understood me" informally, you could say, "You've got it" or "You got it!" But if you want to say (imperative), "Don't understand me!"" you'd say exactly that. Or "Please don't understand me!", but there's no informal way to say that because we so rarely say it. Surely you're not asking for that!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"You got me right" means approximately "You understood me correctly."

"Don't get me wrong" means approximately "Be careful that you do not misunderstand what I say."

Hence it does not necessarily mean "You did not understand me correctly."

Comment: It seems practically *necessary* to include the intensifier ***all*** in *You've got me all wrong!* Which line is very familiar to me from a million-and-one old "crime caper" movies. (But I'm not convinced any real person has ever actually said those words in earnest - it's essentially just boilerplate Hollywood movie script dialogue for "Hero wrongly accused"! :)

Comment: I'm confused, didn't think we were talking about "You got me wrong", thought it was "Don't get me wrong" which is under question. Completely different thing.